# Count number of records processed in jq

Tags: json, stream, jq, reduction, memory-efficient

I'm starting to play with jq and now I stuck when I try to increment a field value while interacting with each object of the input.

Input file has:

```
{"a" : "test1", "b" : 0}
{"a" : "test2", "b" : 0}
{"a" : "test3", "b" : 0}
```

PS: There is no array, only 1 object in each line.

Desired output:

```
{"a" : "test1", "b" : 0}
{"a" : "test2", "b" : 1}
{"a" : "test3", "b" : 2}
```

I found few examples showing how to do with arrays but nothing like this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

jq 1.5 has `inputs`, which opens the door to an efficient solution:

```
jq -nc '
  foreach inputs as $x (-1; .+1; 
    . as $n | $x | .["b"] = $n)' stream.json
{"a":"test1","b":0}
{"a":"test2","b":1}
{"a":"test3","b":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)

```
$ cat input.json |
  jq -sc 'reduce range(0,length) as $i ( .; .[$i].b = ($i+1)) |.[]'
{"a":"test1","b":1}
{"a":"test2","b":2}
{"a":"test3","b":3}
```

Comment: BTW, `jq ... input.json` or `jq ... <input.json` is more efficient than `cat input.json | jq ...`; the former lets the command read straight from the file, not from a FIFO connected to a separate executable that's reading from the file.

Comment: And it's good habit to put all your flags (including `-c`) at the *front* of the command line; [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) only require options to be recognized when they come before the first positional argument, see in particular Guideline 9.